# Update a SageMaker Endpoint After Running a Training Job from a Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

What I am trying to do is automate model retraining, after running the training job from the lambda function, the model artifacts are saved to an S3 bucket.
now what I want to do is to update an existing endpoint with the newly trained model.
any documentation, tutorials, or code examples would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the [SageMaker Model Registry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-registry.html). You can register the output of your training job and automate the deployment by integrating CI/CD.

After you've created a model group in the registry, you can use SageMaker Studio to set up a deployment pipeline for you.

First create a project:

[image: Create SageMaker project]

Select the deployment option:
[image]

This will automatically create a CodePipeline and a CodeCommit repo. The repo houses the build spec and the default `README.md` has some good info on what SageMaker has created for you. Even if you want to customize the CI/CD portion, the default SageMaker projects are a good place to start.

[This walkthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-projects-walkthrough.html#sagemaker-proejcts-walkthrough-create) of a SageMaker project might be useful for you. The model registry plays nicely with SageMaker pipelines as you can simply add a step to register a trained model.